# Trazer contagem de registros "filhos" junto à todos os registros da tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Como faço para contar quantos "filhos" tal linha têm, e ao mesmo tempo listar todos os registros da tabela?
Tenho a tabela `categorias`, com os seguintes dados:

```
 _________________________________
| id (PK)  |  nome  | id_pai (FK) |
 ---------------------------------
|     1    |  ctg1  |     NULL    |
|     2    |  ctg2  |      1      |
|     3    |  ctg3  |      1      |
 ---------------------------------
```

Se eu fizer `SELECT *, COUNT(id_pai) FROM categorias GROUP BY id` tenho o seguinte resultado:

```
 ___________________________________________________
| id (PK)  |  nome  | id_pai (FK) |  COUNT(id_pai)  |
 ---------------------------------------------------
|     1    |  ctg1  |     NULL    |        0        |
|     2    |  ctg2  |      1      |        1        |
|     3    |  ctg3  |      1      |        1        |
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

O resultado que espero é:

```
 ___________________________________________________
| id (PK)  |  nome  | id_pai (FK) |  COUNT(id_pai)  |
 ---------------------------------------------------
|     1    |  ctg1  |     NULL    |        2        |
|     2    |  ctg2  |      1      |        0        |
|     3    |  ctg3  |      1      |        0        |
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Sei que a query está fundamentalmente errada, pois está contando a parte que não quero. Mas como faço para trazer a quantidade de filhos que a linha atual tem junto das informações completa?

Comment: Não sei se funcionaria, não tenho como testar, mas seria algo como... `SELECT *, (SELECT Count(*) FROM categorias WHERE id_pai = cat.id_pai) FROM categorias as cat` ?

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft Quase isso. Retornou como na query que tenho, só que ao invés do count resultar 1, resultou 2. Queria que o count da ctg1 resultasse 2, e os outros 0.

Comment: Tenta mudar para `SELECT *, (SELECT Count(*) FROM categorias WHERE id_pai = cat.id) FROM categorias as cat`

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft Essa query retornou o que eu esperava. Achei a solução nesse meio tempo, mas pode postar a sua resposta que eu aceito como solução.

Comment: Thomas acredito ser melhor você colocar como resposta a solução que você usa... :)

Answer (score 1):

Consegui chegar ao resultado fazendo um LEFT JOIN na própria tabela, juntando com a query que tinha:

`SELECT cat.*, COUNT(cat2.id) FROM categorias AS cat LEFT JOIN categorias cat2 ON cat2.id_pai = cat.id GROUP BY cat.id`

Obs.: A resposta do @RafaelWithoeft nos comentários também funciona. Estou colocando essa como resposta a pedidos.